# R eval(): changed behavior when argument 'envir' is explicitly set to default value

Tags: r, eval

Consider the function `fun1()`. Calling it **does not** assign the value `2` to `xx` in `.GlobalEnv`.

```
fun1 <- function(x) eval(expr=substitute(x)) 
fun1({xx <- 2; xx})
## [1] 2
xx
## Error: object 'xx' not found
```

The default value of the argument `envir` of `eval()` is:

```
formals(eval)$envir
## parent.frame()
```

In `fun2()` the argument `envir` is explicitly set to its default value `parent.frame()`. Calling `fun2()` **does** assign the value `2` to `xx` in `.GlobalEnv`.

```
fun2 <- function(x) eval(expr=substitute(x), envir=parent.frame())
fun2({xx <- 2; xx})
## [1] 2
xx
## [1] 2
```

(Tested with R version 3.5.0)

**Why is that? Is that behavior intended?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Defaults to functions are evaluated in the evaluation frame of the function.  Explicit arguments are evaluated in the calling frame.  (Both of these can be changed by non-standard evaluation tricks, but you're not using those.)

So in your first example, `parent.frame()` is the parent of the call to `eval()`, i.e. the evaluation frame of `fun1()`.  In your second example, `parent.frame()` is the parent of the call to `fun2()`.

Comment: Thanks. Could you be more explicit about the 'non-standard evaluation tricks' to change both behaviors?

Comment: You can use `substitute(arg)` to get the expression passed as an argument, and `eval()` to evaluate it in any environment you choose.  See the Non-standard Evaluation chapter in Wickham's Advanced R Programming book.